# How to send arraylist from activity to another, without visiting that other activity

Tags: java, android

I tried to get an answer for this before but couldn't get one that would solve my problem. 
I'm making app which keeps disc golf scores.
my MainActitivity has 4 buttons. New game, resume game, courses and players.

Atm when user goes to ActivityPlayers (Players button in main activity), user can add and delete players, and shared preferences keep that list save. But now I also need to somehow get that same list of players, to that ActivityNewGame (New game button in main activity), there I need to loop through that list, and use those names to make new items in ActivityNewGame list. (cannot just copy the list from ActivityPlayers straight, because in that recyclerview, those items have different buttons than new game recyclerview has, even tho they use the same list of names.)

I tried to do intent, but I realized that I can't use that because I have to visit that ActivityNewGame when a user adds or delete players from ActivityPlayers...

This is the way I tried

This is my ActivityPlayers.java method. This method will be called when the user adds a new name to mNamelist.

```
private void addItem(int position) {
    /** Get user input (name) **/
    textAdd = findViewById(R.id.name_input);

    /** Add name to the list **/
    mNameList.add(position, new NameItem(textAdd.getText().toString().trim()));

    /** sort that list **/
    sortArrayList();

    /** save changes to shared preferences **/
    saveData();

    /** Show changed list to user **/
    mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(position);

    /** Clear the input field **/
    textAdd.getText().clear();

    /** Send namelist to ActivitynewGame **/
    Intent i = new Intent(ActivityPlayers.this, ActivityNewGame.class);
    i.putExtra("PlayerList", mNameList);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

This is my savedata() method to save changes that user makes for namelist in ActivityPlayers:

```
private void saveData() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("shared preferences", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(mNameList);
    editor.putString("task list", json);
    editor.apply();
}
```

This is my ActivityNewGame:

```
public class ActivityNewGame extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ArrayList<NewGamePlayerItem> mPlayerList;

    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_game);

        mPlayerList = new ArrayList<>();
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        ArrayList<NameItem> mNameList = (ArrayList<NameItem>) intent.getSerializableExtra("PlayerList");

        /** Check if mNameList has any items in it. **/
        if (mNameList.size() != 0) {
        /** Loop through that arraylist and set its names into this Activity items. ("true" is for checkbox that this item has.) **/
            for (int i = 0; i < mNameList.size(); i++) {
                mPlayerList.add(new NewGamePlayerItem(true, mNameList.get(i).getText1()));
            }
        }

        buildRecyclerView();
    }
```

The problem here is that I don't want to visit ActivityNewGame, I just want to pass that name list from ActivityPlayers, and when user choose to go to make a new game (ActivityNewGame), then that player list would be there. So what should I do differently to manage to do that?

Please give me some examples of ideas if you have, thank you.

Comment: hi! to achieve your functionality you can use interface.Take your arraylist into interface and pass that interface into your ActivityNewGame

Comment: why not save the data in sharedPref and access it across the activities in the application?

Comment: @ViVekH It is saved to Shared preferences, but how I can access it in other activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the list static and then you don't need to pass it. You can use it inside your app anywhere you want.

By making it static there may arise `memory leaks` problem so `dispose` them correctly after using it.

Comment: public static Arraylist<NameItem> mNameList? But how I get to it everywhere else?

Comment: After initializing it you can access it with classname where it is declared. Like classname.yourList

Comment: Omg thank u so much! This is so easy, I don't know why no1 told me this earlier...

Comment: Glad it helped you. Also take care of static member as they causes memory leaks so dispose them correctly.

Comment: Means make it null after usage.

Comment: Btw I have problem with this method. When I insert names to my namelist, it makes that list also to ActivityNewGame cool good, but when I close my app and start again, those names are in a list still, but I have to visit ActivityPlayers, to kinda "check" that list, and after that I can see the list in ActivityNewGame. So when I start app and go to ActivityNewGame, I can't see the names, but when I visit ActivityPlayers, and then go to ActivityNewGame, only then it renders the list?

Comment: Any idea why this is?

Answer (score 0):

In ActivityPlayers.java addItem() method, save your data in shared preferences.

```
private void addItem(int position) {
    /** Get user input (name) **/
    textAdd = findViewById(R.id.name_input);

    /** Add name to the list **/
    mNameList.add(position, new NameItem(textAdd.getText().toString().trim()));

    /** sort that list **/
    sortArrayList();

    /** save changes to shared preferences **/
    saveData();

    /** Show changed list to user **/
    mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(position);

    /** Clear the input field **/
    textAdd.getText().clear();

    /** save data to shared pref **/
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS_FILE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
  Editor editor = prefs.edit();
  try {
    editor.putString(<KEY_NAME>, ObjectSerializer.serialize(mNameList));
  } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  editor.commit();
}
```

and in ActivityNewGame.java
extract the ArrayList from shared preferences like so.

```
mNewNameList = new ArrayList<NewGamePlayerItem>();
 // load NewGamePlayerItems from preference
  SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS_FILE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

  try {
    mNewNameList = (ArrayList<NewGamePlayerItem>) ObjectSerializer.deserialize(prefs.getString(<KEY_NAME>, ObjectSerializer.serialize(new ArrayList<NewGamePlayerItem>())));
  } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

Comment: this gives lot of red.
I made SHARED_PREF_FILE ->private static final String SHARED_PREFS_FILE = "shared preferences";
and everything else handled with ALT + ENTER, but what I do with <KEY_NAME> and ObjectSerializer, they are still red...

Comment: key_name is a string, which you will use while saving the shared pref and retrieving it back.

Comment: import this class into your project for ObjectSerializer https://github.com/sudar/android-samples/blob/master/TaskManager/src/com/sudarmuthu/android/taskmanager/util/ObjectSerializer.java

Comment: KEY_NAME still gives error "Cannot resolve symbol 'KEY_NAME'"

Comment: declare it as a variable String key_name="SharedPrefKey";

Comment: String key_name="SharedPrefKey";
        try {
            mPlayerList = (ArrayList<NewGamePlayerItem>) ObjectSerializer.deserialize(prefs.getString(<key_name>, ObjectSerializer.serialize(new ArrayList<NewGamePlayerItem>()));
Error: "Unchecked cast: java.lang.Object to java.util.arraylist<com.example.frisbeecaddy.NewGamePlayerItem>"

Comment: Btw, mNameList and mPlayerList has different item structures. mNamelist items has textview (String) and imageview (int), mPlayerList items has checkbox (boolean) and textview (String), those strings are everything I need out of that mNameList items and insert them into NewGamePlayerItem(s), I don't know does this make any difference tho...

Comment: The arrayList you are saving in sharedPref needs to be cast to the same bean/pojo when retrieving.

Comment: Hmm now saving names with that method works, and also when I close the app and go check the name list, names are there, but when I try to access it in ActivityNewGame, my app crashes

Comment: I think the problem here is that it takes hole name list as it is, and try to put it like that in ActivityNewGame, but as I mentioned earlier, my ActivityPlayer namelist items has different  elements in them than ActivityNewGame has. I only need to get names from ActivityPlayers to ActivityNewGame, could this be that problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use RxBus to send data to another activity without visiting it.

Answer (score 0):

You can save your arraylist in one file.

```
public void save(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException {
String tmp = clubs.toString();
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(fileName));
pw.write(tmp);
pw.close();
}
```